# jquery ui sortable parent and child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to have all options to drag a child as parent and a parent into child elements.

Later a child should be parent if dragged as parent and be able to get child elements.

Is this possible, how to solve it?

This is what I've got:
http://jsfiddle.net/LBybN/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function  () {
        $('ul.nav').sortable({
            connectWith: '.subnav',
        });
        $('ul.subnav').sortable({
        connectWith: '.nav',
        });
    })
</script>

<ul class="nav">
    <li>Web Development</li>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>PHP Jobs</li>
        <li>OSCommerce projects</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Content Creation</li>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>Technical Writing Jobs</li>
        <li>Forum Posting</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Design and Artwork</li>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>Blog Design Projects</li>
        <li>Freelance Website Design</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Sales and Marketing</li>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>Internet Marketing Consulting</li>
        <li>Leads Generation Services</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <ul class="subnav"></ul>
</ul>

<style>
.subnav {
    background-color:orange;
    min-height:10px;
    width:400px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this is not too late for you.
You should try to build each child node as

```
<li>
    <h2>Level 1_2</h2>
    <ul class="nav"></ul>
</li>
```

And change the jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav").sortable({
        connectWith: ".nav"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddler with a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/vzQ2X/1/).